# How to compare year to date figures from the current year with the previous year?

Tags: ssas, mdx, mdx-query

With the bellow MDX query im attempting to return a comparasion of sales, but its not working
For example i want to compare the values from current year until today (29/september/2022) with the values until today's date last year (29/september/2021).

WITH

```
    MEMBER [Measures].[Sales YTD] AS

        'SUM(YTD(closingperiod([Date].[Calendar].[Date])),[Measures].[Sales])'

    MEMBER [Measures].[Sales LYTD] AS

        'SUM(YTD(PARALLELPERIOD([Date].[Calendar].[Calendar Year],1,closingperiod([Date].[Calendar].[Date]))),[Measures].[Sales])'

    SELECT

        {[Measures].[Sales YTD],[Measures].[Sales LYTD]} ON COLUMNS

    ...
```

Can please someone help ?

Comment: Remove the `closingperiod` function, also use `CurrentMember`. You need just: `SUM(YTD([Date].[Calendar].CurrentMember), [Measures].[Sales])`

Comment: I tried your solution but its not working, because its comparing the following dates: (1/january/2022)-(30/september/2022) with (1/january/2021)-(31/december/2021) and i want to compare (1/january/2022)-(30/september/2022) with (1/january/2021)-(30/september/2021).